# Devise does now allow me to sign_in using TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mocking, mocha.js, testcase

I am using Devise to sign in Users. I want to write some tests to ensure everything is running smoothly. My sign in is using Poloymorphism Association.

A User can be a Employer or a Applicant, which is working fine.

I am using the following code and the sign_in helper given by Devise.

```
 def log_in_applicant
    sign_in UserFactory.applicant 
 end
```

This code does not sign_in a user. But when I go into the Rails console debugger and write the code the user become signed in!

Comment: any errors or does it fail silently?

Comment: It fails silently, I discovered the problem by using rails console and explicitly typing in the code. This lead to believe the problem is the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Devise does not allow you to use sign_in helper in TestCase, therefore the code above never signs in a user.

You will need to use mocking to mock a signed in use.

You could use Mocha Gem and write the following code.

```
 def log_in_applicant
    JobsController.any_instance.stubs(:current_user).returns( UserFactory.applicant)
 end
```

- Obviously the user to sign in comes from a UserFactory.
- any_instance.stubs(:current_user) - Says any instance of the :current_user, a helper from      devise should return
- .returns( UserFactory.applicant)
- The JobsController is a reference to the controller you want to test. It is actually a reference to self.current_user is a sense. If you want more info pls ask me :)